# Chai deep equal not working

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, chai

I'm trying to use Chai, but I cannot get the deep equal comparison to work for some reason.

This is a minimum example

```
var chai = require('chai');
var expect = chai.expect;
...


expect({
    test: {a:2}
    }).to.have.deep.property('test', {a:2});
```

That generates this output

```
AssertionError: expected { test: { a: 2 } } to have a deep property 'test' of { a: 2 }, but got { a: 2 }
```

I'm using Chai 3.5.0 and would expect this assertion to be true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to upgrade to a newer version of Chai. This feature was introduced in Chai 4, see [4.x.x Complete Migration Guide](https://github.com/chaijs/chai/issues/781).

Comment: wow, thanks! The first thing I checked was if there was a newer version here http://aaronsofaly.github.io/chai-docs/releases/ but 3.5.0 was the latest there.... But checking on github there is a newer version of course :)

Comment: I can now see that it was googles fault. Those pages I linked are not the offical docs!

Answer (score 1):

For version 4.0.0 they have changed behavior of '.have.deep'
You can see release notes here

[chai releases 4.0.0](https://github.com/chaijs/chai/releases/tag/4.0.0)

I suggest you to update chai if it is possible.